# Error "cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field ClusterRoleBinding.roleRef of type v1.RoleRef" when crewating ClusterRoleBinding in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, k8s-cluster-role

I'm trying to create a ClusterRoleBinding for an exercise in a course with the YAML file below:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nodes-admin
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - delete
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nodes-admin
subjects:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: user1387
roleRef:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: nodes-admin
```

Yet it keeps failing with:

> `Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "clusterrole.yaml": ClusterRoleBinding in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ClusterRoleBinding: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field ClusterRoleBinding.roleRef of type v1.RoleRef`

I investigate for some time but couldn't really understand what is going on. What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `roleRef` field expects *one* object with fields `apiGroup`, `kind` and `name`. When you put the `-` before the `apiGroup` under `roleRef`, you are creating an *array of objects* (containing, sure, only one object, but nonetheless passing the wrong type of value to `roleRef`). The solution is to remove that `-`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nodes-admin
subjects:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: user1387
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io  # ⇦ Changed here
  kind: ClusterRole                    # compare with the
  name: nodes-admin                    # original
```

The error message does actually explain that, even if it may be a bit hard to understand sometimes:

> cannot *unmarshal* **array** *into* Go **struct field** ClusterRoleBinding.roleRef of type v1.RoleRef